# Using FindResource in an IValueConverter

Tags: c#, wpf

I have this value converter which converts a number to a brush color. What I need to do is to change the line `return Brushes.Red;` into `return (Brush)FindResource("PrimaryHueMidBrush");`, so I can return the color of the main theme. The problem is that I don't know how to declare `(Brush)FindResource("PrimaryHueMidBrush");`. Any help is welcome. Thank you in advance.

```
public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
{
    double.TryParse(value.ToString(), out double val);

    if (val == 1)
    {
        return Brushes.Red;
    }
    else if(val == 0.5)
    {
        return Brushes.MediumVioletRed;
    }
    else if(val==0)
    {
        return Brushes.Transparent;
    }
    else
    {
        return Brushes.Transparent;
    }
}

public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
{
    throw new NotImplementedException();
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Instead of calling FindResource in the converter, you'd better add one or more properties for the dynamic Brushes:

```
public class YourConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public Brush FirstBrush { get; set; }
    public Brush SecondBrush { get; set; }

    public object Convert(
        object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        double val = (double)value;

        if (val >= 1)
        {
            return FirstBrush;
        }

        if (val >= 0.5)
        {
            return SecondBrush;
        }

        return Brushes.Transparent;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(
        object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotSupportedException();
    }
}
```

You would declare it in the Resources of your Application or Window like this:

```
<local:YourConverter x:Key="YourConverter"
    FirstBrush="{StaticResource PrimaryHueMidBrush}"
    SecondBrush="MediumVioletRed"/>
```

Comment: Thank you very much, it resolved my issue. You are my hero :D

Comment: sorry, its the first time here for me :D.

Comment: Brilliant! I never would have thought of this on my own.

Answer (score 0):

To access `FindResource` you need a `FrameworkElement` so the best way to do this would probably be to use a `MultiValueConverter` instead and pass the element that uses the converter as a second value.

Converter:

```cs
public class WhateverThisIsCalledConverter : IMultiValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        // Insert type- and sanity-checks here
        double val = (double)values[0];
        FrameworkElement callingElement = (FrameworkElement)values[1];

        if (val >= 1)
        {
            return callingElement.FindResource("PrimaryHueMidBrush");
        }
        if (val >= 0.5)
        {
            return Brushes.MediumVioletRed;
        }

        return Brushes.Transparent;
    }

    public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return Enumerable.Repeat(DependencyProperty.UnsetValue, targetTypes.Length).ToArray();
    }
}
```

Usage in XAML:

```xaml
<Window.Resources>
    <local:WhateverThisIsCalledConverter x:Key="Converter"/>
    <SolidColorBrush Color="Red" x:Key="PrimaryHueMidBrush"/>
</Window.Resources>
<Grid>
    <Grid.Background>
        <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource Converter}">
            <Binding Path="Value"/>
            <Binding RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Self}"/>
        </MultiBinding>
    </Grid.Background>
</Grid>
```

Couple of notes on your current implementation:

- Try avoiding `==` on doubles, they are not infinitely precice.
- You don't need all those `else`s when you `return` in the `if` before.
- The `ConvertBack` method should be implemented (Free choice of other Exceptions, `Binding.DoNothing` and `DependencyProperty.UnsetValue`).
- If you know your value is a double, simply cast it instead.

Comment: As for the last note, you should show that in your code sample. You'd also need to check the result of `values[1] as FrameworkElement` for null, or also better directly cast it.

Comment: @Clemens Yeah, the code isn't fool proof since I had to make a lot of assumptions - it also contains no sanity-checks.